# PCB Design - Routing Around GND under Chip

Tags: pcb-design

I'm just wondering if anyone has any advise on how to/whether it is acceptable to route around a GND location on the back of a chip?

Say for example you have two tracks either side of a chip you wish to connect to - can you connect them under the chip if there is a GND panel in the centre if you navigate a 10 mil route around the side of it?

[image]

Comment: Normally you'd drop a via and go under on a different layer, but if you can fit it (and the part will actually be manufacturable with those close traces) you can do that.

Comment: The datasheet might have routing/layout suggestions but usually EP packages also suggest a large contiguous pour on the backside for heat dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions must be answered:

1. Does the path degrade the performance (including reliability) of the circuit? If it does then no. We cannot answer that question for you because it depends on the circuit and the application.
2. Is it manufacturable? Ask the board house that you intend to use. 6/6 mil track width/spacing is easy to come by. 4/4 mil track width/spacing or finer is available at higher prices.

If you answer No to the first and Yes to the second, then go for it.

Comment: Remember to pay attention to the dimensions of the exposed pad on the device, too, not just on the board. You don't want to be relying on soldermask to insulate a bit of exposed pad from this non-ground trace.